# C Pointer Arithmetic Strange Behavior

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following seemingly simple piece of code:

```
void freeBin(MallocHeader * pBinHeader){
    while(pBinHeader){
        MallocHeader * pNext = pBinHeader->pNext;
        pBinHeader->magic = K_MAGIC_NUM;
        printf("Orig magic and size = %i %lu\n", pBinHeader->magic, pBinHeader->size);
        void * freeAddr = pBinHeader + sizeof(MallocHeader);
        MallocHeader * actual = freeAddr - sizeof(MallocHeader);
        printf("Pre free magic and size = %i %lu\n", actual->magic, actual->size);
        free(freeAddr);
        pBinHeader = pNext;
    }
}
```

The output of the first printf call does not match the output of the second printf call. But by simple arithmetic, 'actual' should match 'pBinHeader'. What have I missed?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but you should stick with `char *` pointers when doing arithmetic for an allocator. See if that helps.

Comment: I want to ask for clarification on the question, based on your accepted answer. That solution will make the `printf` statements match, but I want to make sure that's what you want. Do you want to move the pointer from `pBinHeader` forward by `sizeof(MallocHeader)` _bytes_? Or by a _count_ of `sizeof(MallocHeader)` _units_, where 1 unit is the size of `pBinHeader`? If the latter, the accepted solution is correct. If the former, you need to cast the pointers to `char *` before doing arithmetic, or add/subtract 1 from them.

Comment: A suggestion on code formatting: do not put spaces on both sides of the `*` when declaring or dereferencing a pointer. Even though the compiler doesn't care, it's visually confusing, making it look like you are multiplying. For example, either write `MallocHeader* pNext` or `MallocHeader *pNext`. Some developers (like myself) prefer the former, others use the latter. Whichever you choose, use it consistently. This helps make it clear that you are working with pointers, not multiplying two values.

Comment: @bnaecker Seems he  likes it, maybe will change mind after pointers will perform...

Comment: @bnaecker I ended up adding 1 to pBinHeader to obtain the correct address as a void pointer. I will work on the formatting. Three years of doing it improperly will be hard to correct :( This style is much more common in Objective-C programs, the language I learned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two different pointer arithmetic methods.

When adding 1 to `freeAddr` (type void* ) the pointer is being incremented by 1.
(This is an extension. In C void* pointers cannot be used in pointer arithmetic )

When adding 1 to `pBinHeader` (type MallocHeader*) the pointer is being incremented by `sizeof(MallocHeader)`.

The solution is to declare the `pBinHeader` with the correct pointer type:

```
MallocHeader* freeAddr = pBinHeader + sizeof(MallocHeader);
MallocHeader * actual = freeAddr - sizeof(MallocHeader);
```

or cast the pointer:

```
void * freeAddr = pBinHeader + sizeof(MallocHeader);
MallocHeader * actual = (MallocHeader*)freeAddr - sizeof(MallocHeader);
```